# How to manage session in spring MVC in following case?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, javabeans

```
@Controller

@SessionAttributes( {"user"})
@RequestMapping("/")
public class Logincontroller {

    @Autowired
    public Loginservice loginservice;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getPage1() {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("login");
        return view;
    }

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value="Userprofileservice")
    public Userprofileservice userprofile;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/processLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public ModelAndView processLogin(HttpServletRequest request,
               HttpServletResponse response) {
          String userName=request.getParameter("username");  
          String password=request.getParameter("password"); 




        if (loginservice.checklogin(userName,password)) {

                     /* ModelAndView success = new ModelAndView("success");*/
            ModelAndView success = new ModelAndView("success");
            List<Users_main>  user = userprofile.userdetails(userName);
              success.addObject("username", userName);
              success.addObject("user",user);
                      return success;
                  } else {

                      ModelAndView error = new ModelAndView("error");
                      return error;
                  }

              } 



    }
```

This is my controller code. My idea is to keep success.jsp page after successful login & keep logged in even after refresh also. But when I hit "/" it is going to login. How can redirect it to success.jsp page even after refresh in same session? I tried with session attribute in controller but it didn't seems to be working

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Spring Security to do it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use [HttpSession](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) which is comes from `javax.servlet` api.

For creating new session you can call

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
```

This will return a new session object. So put any object or value in the session in such that,

```
session.setAttribute("user", user);
```

Assuming that your `user` object is returned from service layer.

Now you can access the user object anytime (if session timeout doesn't occur) in the whole project by

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
```

Here we set boolean `false` confirm that if any session are still alive in the application context for the request, then returns it. Now accessing the session value by

```
User user = (User)session.getAttribute("user");
```

So modify your controller with that and try again the code below,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/processLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView processLogin(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
    String userName=request.getParameter("username");  
    String password=request.getParameter("password"); 

    if (loginservice.checklogin(userName,password)) {

            /* ModelAndView success = new ModelAndView("success");*/
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

            ModelAndView success = new ModelAndView("success");
            List<Users_main>  user = userprofile.userdetails(userName);
            success.addObject("username", userName);
            success.addObject("user",user);
            session.setAttribute("user",user);
            return success;
        } else {
            ModelAndView error = new ModelAndView("error");
            return error;
        }

}
```

Let me know the status.